# Typescript: Index based callback parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am currently trying to create a function that accepts data of a specific type ("resource") as well as an array of arrays where each entry holds a call object and a callback for when that call finishes ("handlers").

```
function useHandleResource<
  R extends ReturnType<typeof useApi>,
  H extends [ReturnType<typeof useCall>, ((data: R['data'], cp: H[number]['0']['callParam']) => R['data'])?][]
>(
  resource: R,
  handlers: H
)
```

The return value of "useApi" holds a "data" property of a generic type.
The return value of "useCall" holds a "callParam" property of a generic type.

When I use this function I want typescript to give me the right types in the callback parameters.

```
useHandleResource(
  testResource(), // "data" has the type "string[]" 
  [
    [
      testCall(), // "callParam" has the type "string",
      // data should have type "string[]" and "cp" should have the type "string" from the callParam from testCall
      (data, cp) => []
    ]
  ]
);
```

This doesn't throw an error, but the "cp" parameter in the callback is "unknown"...

And I want to be able to pass in multiple handlers where each has the corresponding "cp" type.

```
[
  [
    testCall(), // "callParam" has the type "string",
    // cp should have type "string"
    (data, cp) => [cp]
  ],
  [
    otherTestCall(), // "callParam" has type "number",
    // cp should have type "number"
    (data, cp) => [cp.toString()]
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using a rest parameter this will work using a mapped type:

```
type HandlerMap<TData, T> =  {
  [P in keyof T]: [Call<T[P]>, (data: TData, v: T[P]) => any]
}

type Call<T> = { callParam: T }
declare function useHandleResource<
  TData extends { data: any }, 
  TCallParam extends any[]
>(resources: TData, ...handlers: HandlerMap<TData['data'], TCallParam>): any


useHandleResource(
  { data: [""] },
  [
      { callParam: "" },
      (data, cp) => [cp] //cp string
  ],
  [
      { callParam: 0 },
      (data, cp) => [cp.toExponential()] //cp number
  ]
);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgOwCYBsICcCycwB4AqAInMHADRT4B8UAvFFAN4CwAUAwNoAKUAlglADWEEAHsAZpQC6ALigcAwnBQoC3KVQoAKJCThyieigDcD6gJR0aiEFLYBfNm1CQoSlQRr1GUAMbKULjh0OABbAyhHViQIXxRg6HEAVwRfYF5RASSAZwh4ZDQAJQhs0ST0XwhcNgZDUigIAA9gCGRspihdUjkbSIoayndA4LCG5takdpsOO1YqLXQSsoqSg2JSCgA6bYALRFQMbLl8g6wcAnW4DgByLrhrqQp8IaCQ0KpzHoQQJ1Y2HLy+yKS3KlS0Ax8dzkHAARDCpH0BhwBgwGD5-CpXmE5HDEexUQwdEY-GBLLQaBxfGAEQB6GlUqDZYDofgAcwGjyRKNR6ICWPCUAADHiCYS7hQqWSKVTNsBRABRRpgTKtdLKLTmWn0sBQBBJUIAIwwHLY5gA3EA)

**Edit**

Just realized that adding a constraint to make `T` a tuple will make regular arrays work as well:

```
type HandlerMap<TData, T> =  {
  [P in keyof T]: [Call<T[P]>, (data: TData, v: T[P]) => any]
}

type Call<T> = { callParam: T }
declare function useHandleResource<
  TData extends { data: any }, 
  TCallParam extends [any] | any[]
>(resources: TData, handlers: HandlerMap<TData['data'], TCallParam>): any


useHandleResource(
  { data: [""] },[
  [
      { callParam: "" },
      (data, cp) => [cp] //cp string
  ],
  [
      { callParam: 0 },
      (data, cp) => [cp.toExponential()] //cp number
  ]
  ]
);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgOwCYBsICcCycwB4AqAInMHADRT4B8UAvFFAN4CwAUAwNoAKUAlglADWEEAHsAZpQC6ALigcAwnBQoC3KVQoAKJCThyieigDcD6gJR0aiEFLYBfNm1CQoSlQRr1GUAMbKULjh0OABbAyhHViQIXxRg6HEAVwRfYF5RASSAZwh4ZDQAJQhs0ST0XwhcNgZDUigIAA9gCGRspihdUjkbSIoayndA4LCG5takdo4bKSgAHygbDjtWKi10ErKKkoNiUgoAC0RUDGy5fJOsHAI9uA4Aci64e6kKfCGgkNCqcx6EECcrDYOTyxyKm3KlS0Ax8TzkHAARAjZvYyBwBuj2AxsT5-CpPmE5Ei+gNsVAdEY-GBLLQaBxfGBZgB6JkMqDZYDofgAcwGrwxpJxfgCBPCUAADCSsWSKfsqTS6QyAHTAUQAUUaYEyrXSyi05mZrLAUAQSVCACMMHzraxzABuIA)

Comment: Thank you!
This works and I don't mind using a rest parameter, but I wonder is it even more complex to do so with an array?

Comment: @BillTheBob Just realised how to do the array version. added to the answer